# Cordova socialSharingPlugin - how to tell which service the user shared content with

Tags: facebook, cordova, ios-sharesheet

I use the [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/) port of the excellent [cordovaSocialSharing plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) written by [Eddy Verbruggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2596974/eddy-verbruggen), using the method to share with the native sharesheet. I would like to know which option the user chose to share with, e.g. facebook, twitter etc. Is it possible to get this information?

The success callback "result" object is just a boolean.

```
    $cordovaSocialSharing
    //message, subject, file, url
      .share(null, null, null, video.video_url) // Share via native share sheet
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log("success sharing video!", result);
      }, function (err) {
        console.log("error sharing video!", err);
      });
```